# how to get image location from database using ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on my website using wordpress to view and change cover for user by clicking on photo and then redirect him for example to `process.php?pid=12`

I am using

```
switch($GetPicId)
{
```

So I can't add more pic I but now I have script to upload pic using database, and I wanna to get id and pic location from by using database

First this is the [upload script](http://www.sourcecodester.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/commentsys_0.zip)

and this is switch code

```
    $GetPicId = $_GET["pid"]; // Picture ID from Index page
$PicLocation ='';

/*
Users do not need to know original location of image.
I think it's better to get image location from database using ID.
for demo here i'am using PHP switch.
*/
switch($GetPicId)
{
    case 1:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover1.jpg';
        break;
    case 2:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover2.jpg';
        break;
    case 3:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover3.jpg';
        break;
    case 4:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover4.jpg';
        break;
    case 5:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover5.jpg';
        break;
    case 6:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover6.jpg';
        break;
    case 7:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover7.jpg';
        break;
    case 8:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover8.jpg';
        break;
    case 9:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover9.jpg';
        break;
    case 10:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover10.jpg';
        break;
    case 11:
        $PicLocation = 'cover_pics/cover11.jpg';
        break;
    default:
        header('Location: ' . $homeurl);
        break;
}
```

Comment: If you want just a basic query, try the code I've given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try

```
$GetPicId = $_GET["pid"]; // Picture ID from Index page
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT piclocation FROM tableName WHERE pid=$GetPicId") or die(mysql_error());
$res=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$PicLocation = $res['piclocation '];
```

Comment: thanks really it help but can u tell me how can i make a complete code
working  on wordpress cuz wordpress dir " www.4egx.com "
and app on app/process.php so all i need to change switch and make complete code get id and image location from database i hope all understand :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get attachment url ..Your cover images are uploaded in media right??

Then try this

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); ?>
```

it will become something like this

```
 $GetPicId = $_GET["pid"]; // Picture ID from Index page

 $PicLocation =wp_get_attachment_url( $GetPicId);
```

Comment: your code is help but can u tell me if i using wordpress and file location will be for example  http://www.4egx.com/wp-content/uploads/200.jpg

and id will be http://www.4egx.com/?attachment_id=7 

all i need now complete code to get this id and location and remove switch cuz wordpress on www.4egx.com